# Launch corridors

Tags: launch, launch-site, launchpad, launch-sequence

I was wondering where I could find a list of the launch azimuth ranges - i.e. the corridors - for the main launchpads worldwide (Baikonur, Kourou, KSC, ... as many as possible).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you interested in range safety? Without doglegs, you can launch to any orbit with an inclination equal or greater that your launch site's latitude. As long as you're fine dropping spent stages on populated areas. See [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12618/how-are-different-spaceports-restrained-in-terms-of-orbits-reachable) for some info.

Comment: [Here](http://www.astronautix.com/o/orbitallaunchsite.html) is a list of launch sites with minimum and maximum achievable orbital inclinations. These are highly dependent on the launch azimuths, but small local exclusion sectors are not taken into account

Comment: @Jack the link is dead.

Comment: @Heopps Odd, it’s working for me. It’s [astronautix.com](http://www.astronautix.com/index.html) > launch sites > orbital launch sites

Comment: The [Minotaur User's Guide](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/Minotaur/Documents/minotaurIV_VUsersGuide.pdf) has a nice diagram showing the allowable azimuths (and hence inclinations) for USA launch sites.  As @Jack mentioned, the constraints are driven by rang safety.