# Why does Vandenberg have the most launches?

Tags: launch, rockets, launch-site, united-states, space-force

Why does [Vandenberg SFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandenberg_Space_Force_Base) have the most launches? Is it related to location, when it was founded, something else, etc?

It would make more sense for Florida to have more launches. It is illegal for rockets to fly over the U.S. mainland, so rockets from Florida launches from the east, giving them an extra 1000 miles per hour from the rotational velocity of Earth, while rockets from Vandenberg lose 1000 miles per hour from the rotational velocity of Earth. This makes it easier to launches from Florida. So, why does Vandenberg have the most launches?

Comment: What payloads launch from Vandenberg vs Florida? Who launches them?

Comment: Vandenberg does not launch east; it is used for polar orbits, so the loss of 1000 mph is not correct.

Comment: I know, it launches west @OrganicMarble

Comment: Polar orbit launches from Vandenberg go south. The launch limits at Vandenberg are 201 and 158 degrees. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12619/6944

Comment: What about non-polar orbits, which make up most orbits

Comment: Not 'most' from Vandenberg.

Comment: Just an FYI re: Vandenburg launch facility.  It is a small remnant of a giant WWII army base called Camp Cook.  My wife and her brother and mother stayed there in WWII while her father was in the Army in New Guinea for 2 years.   She just had her 80th birthday.  This is not related to the question but I thought I would throw that out.  I would really check the statement that Vandenburg has the most launches.  I will try to verify that.

Comment: Vandenberg's size and mild climate and unobstructed access to the Pacific Ocean made it an ideal test and training site for ballistic missiles.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandenberg_Space_Force_Base

Comment: I am skeptical about your statistics. I found data on Cape Canaveral launches from 1950 through 1999, and they totaled 3182. On the other hand, over the same period, Vandenberg had 1950 launches. Do you have a reference for your data? Here are mine: https://www.spaceline.org/history-cape-canaveral/first-launch-cape-canaveral/painting-by-numbers-a-statistical-analysis-of-cape-canaveral-launches/ and https://www.spacearchive.info/vafblog.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because not all orbits should be launched from the east. Polar and retrograde orbits exist too and are very popular. Additionally, Vandenberg is closer to some rocket production facility, making launching from there easier.

Answer (score 7):

Vandenberg does what the Cape cannot do easily: polar and retrograde orbits.  These are very popular with a very large customer: the military.

Comment: ( *   Vandenberg )

Comment: note that polar launches can be, and have been, done from Florida, e.g. [SAOCOM 1B](https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/08/31/spacex-launches-first-polar-orbit-mission-from-florida-in-decades/).  So this answer is mildly hyperbolic.